# Render markdown with math wrapped in escaped parenthesis / brackets to PDF?

Tags: pdf, latex, markdown, pandoc

Background / use case: https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/386/how-does-chatgpt-render-math-in-markdown-output

The `\( ... \)` syntax in markdown corresponds to LaTex math inline mode, and the `\[ ... \]` corresponds to non-inline LaTex math.

Example:

ChatGPT Web UI renders this markdown output `is \( 2^4 = 16 \).`

as:

[image]

Is there a tool that allow me to render markdown file with such inline math notations to PDF correctly?

`pandoc` could probably do the job, but I'm not sure what options / flags to use to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, pandoc can convert this inline `\( 2^4 = 16 \)` syntax.

All you need to do is enable `tex_math_single_backslash` [extension](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-tex_math_single_backslash) like this:

```
pandoc test.md -f markdown+tex_math_single_backslash -o test.pdf
```